# Express.js - Import routes into subroute

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to build an modular express.js server with a good structure.
Tryed to use the different routes as the components in react.

**index.js**

```
var syncsingle = require('./XYZ/syncsingle');
app.get('/sync', syncsingle);
```

**syncsingle.js**

```
if ( ** cool things **){
    var one = require ('./XYZ/sync/one');
    app.use('/sync', one);
}else{
    var two = require ('./XYZ/sync/two');
    app.use('/sync', two);
}
```

Maybe someone could help me out with that issue?
The code which is written in one.js and two.js should be just imported/included at the app.use(..) point. (e.g. in PHP the include('blaa.php') thing).

Thank you very much <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the middleware or sub-app directly to your main app.

```
// index.js
var sync = require("./syncsingle.js")
app.use("/sync", sync)

// syncsingle.js
if ( ** cool things **){
  module.exports = require ('./XYZ/sync/one');
} else {
  module.exports = require ('./XYZ/sync/two');
}
```

It's also common to pass configuration to sub-apps or middleware.

```
var one = require ('./XYZ/sync/one');
var two = require ('./XYZ/sync/two');

module.exports = function sync(options) {
  if ( ** cool things based on options ** ){
    return one;
  else {
    return two;
  }
}
```

In your main app file:

```
app.use("/sync", sync({ useOne: true })
```